# Memory leak when adding an object to vector<unique_ptr<Type>>

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks, unique-ptr

I am using Visual Leak Detector and it says that I have memory leak when I am adding an object to `vector<unique_ptr<Worker>> Workers`.

I got base class named `Worker` with private field name and one Derived class `Builder` with private int bricks.

This is how I add new object to `vector Workers`.

```
    Builder b = Builder(name, stoi(bricks));
    Workers.push_back(make_unique<Builder>(b)); // this is the line with memory leak
```

Can you tell me what should I do to prevent memory leaks in this case?

EDIT:

I release memory of vector like this:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Worker>>().swap(Workers);
```

Implementation of `Worker & Builder`

```
Worker::Worker(string name)
{
    this->_name = name;
}
```

the destructor of Worker is blank.

```
Worker::~Worker()
{

}

Builder::Builder(string name, int bricks) : Worker(name)
{
    this->_bricks = bricks;
}
```

And destructor of Builder is blank.

```
Builder::~Builder()
{

}
```

Comment: Does `Worker` have a `virtual` destructor?

Comment: Can you show the implementations of `Worker` & `Builder`

Comment: Worker's destructor is blank as there is only private: string name;

Comment: In this case you need to make the Worker destructor virtual so it would destroy it as Builder and any members of it and not just as Worker. (I guess also has some virtual methods overridden by Builder, it is basically a rule that class with virtual method must have a virtual destructor - or protected destructor so that delete cannot be called on it).

Comment: You are deleting from the base class pointer and the base class destructor isn't virtual, so you are hitting undefined behavior

Comment: Thank you axalis and Dave S. Axalis as you were first, please answer my question and I will approve it. Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: Is there some reason you create two `Builder` objects when you only need one? Why not `Workers.push_back(make_unique<Builder>(name, stoi(bricks)));`?

Comment: Its just example, the orginal code is more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the Worker destructor virtual so it would destroy it as Builder and any members of it and not just as Worker.

I guess also has some virtual methods overridden by Builder, it is basically a rule that class with virtual method must have a virtual destructor - or protected destructor so that delete cannot be called on it (which would of course prevent its use in unique_ptr).